# JavaScript push an object variable into array occur that value changed

Tags: javascript

An example, I declared an object `json` and in a for loop, I change the json's value and push it into the list2, But It didn't output the value what I expected.

```
var json = {
    value: '',
    text: '',
};

let list = [
    {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3
    },
    {
        a: 4,
        b: 5,
        c: 6
    }
];
let list2 = [];
for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    json.value = list[i].a;
    json.text = list[i].b;

    list2.push(json);
}

console.log(list2)
```

the expected output is

```
list2 = [
    {
        value: 1,
        text: 2,
    },
    {
        value: 4,
        text: 5,
    }
];
```

but the fact is:

```
list2 = [
    {
        value: 4,
        text: 5,
    },
    {
        value: 4,
        text: 5,
    }
];
```

Why?

**PS:I know how to avoid this question, But I can't understand why it happened**

Comment: Because you're pushing the same `json` object twice to the array. Make a check: `list2[0] === list2[1]` => `true`.

Comment: Pushing the object doesn't make a copy of it, you're pushing the same object every time.

Comment: you could push an object in single line: `list2.push({ value: list[i].a, text: list[i].b })`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference

Comment: Hello @afraid.jpg, The issue with your JSON variable which is re-assign the value with the latest value every time. you should use newly assign variable while push in array or you should directly assign inline.

Comment: @Barmar You means that `push()`'s params passing like a pointer? Every times I pushed the `json`, `list2` accepted the memory address of `json`?

Comment: Yes, all variable assignments and parameter passing in JS uses references, it doesn't make copies, analogous to pointers in C.

Comment: There's a deep explanation: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-8-evaluation-strategy/#call-by-sharing (the link found from ures6445533's answer in the post linked above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript has 5 data types that are **passed by value**: Boolean, null, undefined, String, and Number. Called primitive types.

Javascript has 3 data types that are **passed by reference**: Array, Function, and Object.

So in your case, `json` is an object and changing its value will be reflecting as referencial.

> A variable holding an object does not "directly" hold an object. What
>   it holds is a reference to an object. When you assign that reference
>   from one variable to another, you're making a copy of that reference.
>   Now both variables hold a reference to an object. Modifying the object
>   through that reference changes it for both variables holding a
>   reference to that object.

Although you have list array, pushing json is pushing its reference in it.

Answer (score -1):

Issue with your json object which is not initialize so after iteration its having the reference to letest one value.

```js
let list = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  },
  {
    a: 4,
    b: 5,
    c: 6
  }
];

let list2 = [];
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list2.push({
    value: list[i].a,
    text: list[i].b
  });
}

console.log(list2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: OP asked for an explanation, not the code how to fix.

Comment: @Teemu .. ri8 :)

Comment: Agreed, that's why I have changed it, but my concern is about to show him best way to iterate, but that's not a point obviously, Ha Ha.. Thank you @Teemu